# In Drupal 7 I cant override the template in the parent theme through the child theme. How do I fix this?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

Ive spent hours trying to figure this out and nothing works...What can I do?!  It seems like this should be automatic but its hard to find a solution..

Comment: THE ANSWER :  I just had to flush the page cache it turns out. I spent something like five hours wasted on this but flush the cache and see what happens.

Comment: The golden rule! if you have a Drupal problem, first flush the cache and then investigate, ask a question...

Answer (score 0):

I just had to flush the page cache it turns out. I spent something like five hours wasted on this but flush the cache and see what happens.  You can also turn on theme registry for production sites.